# How to add a separate line between .deepToString output?

Tags: java

Wondering how to add a separate line between .deepToString output.

Current output looks like: `[[true, false, true], [false, true, false]]` when it is intended to have a separate line to split each row in a separate line.

Comment: you'll need to write your own method I think

Comment: Can you show us how exactly are you looking it to be?

Comment: The desired output is:  [[true, false, true], \n [false, true, false]]

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.replace()`

```
output.deepToString().replace("],", "],\n");
```

Thanks @Kartik for letting me know about replace() for non regex replaces

Comment: Use `replace()` if it's not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick

```
public String array2DToString( boolean[][] array){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( "[");
    String delimiter = "";
    for( boolean[] row : array){
        builder.append( delimiter).append( Arrays.toString( row));
        delimiter = System.lineSeparator();
    }
    builder.append( "]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

StringBuilder is better way of concatenating String. since Arrays.toString works fine for single dimension we can just use that. then you can change delimiter to whatever you want to separate rows.

you can also modify the function and pass delimiter as an argument to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like following:

`Arrays.deepToString(aComplexArray).replaceAll("], ", System.lineSeparator());`

Off course, it might incorrectly start the line if the array elment contain the string "], ".

Comment: Use `replace()` if it's not a regex.

Comment: @Kartik, can you elaborate?

Comment: [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is used to replace a regex with a string, while [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) is used to replace a string with another string. You are replacing `"], "`, which is not a regex, just a normal string.

Comment: Right. And that's what we need to replace here.